# myGeolocation javascript in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, geolocation

Am trying to get the lat/long values for a specific address in c# and I want to use the myGeoloaction-API for this. (I know there is google, bing and whatever, but myGeoloaction is free)

But myGeoloaction only provides Javascript code that open a popup with there GeoPicker.

```
<script src="http://api.mygeoposition.com/api/geopicker/api.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookupGeoData() {            
        myGeoPositionGeoPicker({
            startAddress     : 'White House, Washington',
            returnFieldMap   : {
                                 'geoposition1a' : '<LAT>',
                                 'geoposition1b' : '<LNG>',
                                 'geoposition1c' : '<CITY>',   /* ...or <COUNTRY>, <STATE>, <DISTRICT>,
                                                                       <CITY>, <SUBURB>, <ZIP>, <STREET>, <STREETNUMBER> */
                                 'geoposition1d' : '<ADDRESS>'
                               }
        });
    }
</script>

Geo-Coordinates:
<input type="text" name="geoposition1a" id="geoposition1a" size="10">
<input type="text" name="geoposition1b" id="geoposition1b" size="10">
<input type="text" name="geoposition1c" id="geoposition1c" size="10">
<input type="text" name="geoposition1d" id="geoposition1d" size="70">
<button type="button" onclick="lookupGeoData();">GeoPicker</button>
```

My question is can I use this javascript in c# to get the lat/long values back?

Comment: Yes, you can call Javascript function from C# and pass your lat/long in the function for C# side. Below is the example, please add parameters in JS function. Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. There is a project called 'CEFsharp',which can analyse/execute javascript(actually ,it can even work as a embedded-fully functional-browser).

But i guess the effort would be too much if u just want to locate an address into lat/long.The js are transferred into HTTP request at last, so why not just find out the row request data and use it in your program?

By using wireshark or burpsuite or whatever tools you want,you can easily catch the request and customize your program.